# Android - How to achieve vibration pattern without pause/delay?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vibration

How to make continuous vibration without a pause or delay. I tried custom patterns like `{0, 100, 1000, 300, 200}` but they vibrate with breaks, even if I set the break to 0.

Is there any way or trick to achieve it because I saw the continuous patter in an application https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jgdevlabs.vibra So, there must be a way to achieve it.

Please help me with this or by sharing the question so that anybody could help :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe continuous vibration can be achieved simply like that.

**It will vibrate for as long as you want.**

```
final Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

         Timer _timer = new Timer();

        _timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(cancelVibration==true){
                    cancel();
                }
                v.vibrate(1000);
            }
        },0, 50);
```